# Fitting a Vertical Line to Points on a Plot

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, modeling

I have the following data, which produced the following plot.

```
Predictor_Variable <- c(rnorm(1000, 0, 25), rnorm(1000, 20, 2), rnorm(100, 20, 10))
Response_Variable <- c(rnorm(1000, 0, 2), rnorm(1000, 0, 25), rnorm(100, 0, 10))
Data_Frame <- data.frame(Predictor_Variable = Predictor_Variable, Response_Variable = Response_Variable)
plot(Response_Variable ~ Predictor_Variable, Data_Frame, main = 'Example Plot', xlab = 'Predictor Variable', ylab = 'Response Variable')
```

[image]

I need to fit a vertical line to the points on the plot that extend vertically up and down from the horizontal axis. This vertical portion is not perfectly centered, so I can't simply take the average of the values.

Is there a nice, programmatic way of finding this vertical line?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33078 has answers.  So does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581275.  And even https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375787/.

Comment: If you're "fitting" a response in terms of a predictor, you're presumably trying to fit something like the conditional mean $E{Y|X=x)$. The wide spread of Y when x is close to 0 doesn't make the conditional *mean* go 'vertical'. It might pay to investigate what caused this behavior, which probably should start with looking at what the response measures and how the response is obtained (e.g. such an appearance is not uncommon when Y is a ratio of two things that may both take values close to 0). It may be that a model for the spread is needed ...,

Comment: ... or it may be that you need to look at the variables involved in a different way. Wanting to fit the "vertical" part would involve departing from "fitting Y given X=x" perspective

Comment: Your data is simulated from a mixture of three multi-normal distributions. Do you know that your actual data is a sample from a mixture of three (approximately multi-normal) distributions? Why are your two variables called "predictor"  and "response" when in your simulation they are completely independent of each other?

Comment: @whuber - thank you for the excellent tip - the Hough Transform sounds like the perfect solution

Comment: @Roland - I simulated data for this reproducible example, but my actual data don't necessarily follow a normal distribution, nor are the predictor and response variables completely independent