# Turning heatmap into clusters - Classification

Tags: classification, clustering, k-means, heatmap

Assume that you having a heatmap that looks like this. The goal is to classify all the "dot" inside the image. How can that be done?

The assumptions of the image:

- The image has always black background
- The white is values that are around 100 or more.
- In each cluster, there are only one maximum value

[image]

I want to know

- How many clusters there are
- The radius of the clusters

To do so, I need to separate them into different clusters. But how can that be done?

Comment: It depends on what you really mean by a "cluster", why you want to do this, and the expected geometries of the clusters.  For instance, I describe and illustrate a workflow for clustering a Hough transform at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/581400/919.  Although it works well for *that form* of data, it wouldn't necessarily be a good idea in other applications, which is why these details matter.  See, for instance, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20696 for a rather different approach.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your reply. This plot is actually a hough transform. I'm seeking advice how to improve the findings of the peaks.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions I linked to?

Comment: @whuber I solved this issue by DBscan, on x-axis and y-axis only. `[x, y] = find(A)` and make a cluster identification using dbscan onto matrix `[x y]`