# Image processing: Inferre rotation angle of tilted rectangle on noisy background

Tags: regression, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I have many "grayscale" images i.e. 2d-arrays like the following:

[image: image of a slightly tilted dark rectangle on bright background]

i.e. dark rectangles which are tilted by an angle $\alpha \in [-3^\circ, 3^\circ]$ and a bright but noisy background. I have a (rather slow) method to determine the angle based on Hough transform, thus I have sufficient training data.

Question: Is there any machine learning based method to deduce the angle $\alpha$ efficiently and robustly? Precision should be at $\pm 0.3^\circ$.

Comment based **update**: Apart from solving the problem "somehow" analytically (e.g. by Fourier transform) I am mainly interested in how such a problem could in principle be solved by machine learning (e.g. which architecture to use).

Comment: It looks like ML is scarcely necessary: just run an edge detector over the image and go from there.  Another technique would be to compute the 2D Fourier transform: it will have peaks at $\alpha$ plus integral multiples of 90°.  BTW, in what sense is this *color* image "grayscale"?

Comment: @whuber edge detection will probably not work because I need sub-pixel precision. I will try Fourier transform. "Grayscale" is meant that it is only one channel (as opposed to RGB). In the shown image the value range is visualized with the [viridis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#sequential) colormap of matplotlib.

Comment: I don't understand how "sub-pixel precision" might be related to the angle of rotation or even of edge detectors.  The image itself by definition has *exactly* one pixel of precision, but estimates derived from it--being aggregates of that information--can be very precise.

Comment: I would suggest edge detection (and thresholding) to get the outlines of the box, then image moments to get the orientation http://raphael.candelier.fr/?blog=Image%20Moments and see subpixel section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

Comment: The solution I posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/581400/919 gives 89.6 degrees (equivalently, -0.4 degrees) for this image.

Comment: conv neural nets basically are adaptive forms of standard image processing algorithms. for your application, you could convert your existing alg into neural net. You have a bank of edge detection filters. then hough transform is a single filter that sums values in each rotation ("weight sharing"), rather than the typical cnn where the same  filter repeated at constant shifts across the image

Comment: The method of image proposed by @seanv507 is very fast and works quite well (even without tresholding and edge detection). In opencv (which I use from Python) the relevant method is https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga556a180f43cab22649c23ada36a8a139